# How can we retrieve query string information in a ClickOnce Application?

Tags: .net, clickonce, query-string

I made a .NET Windows Forms application that I want to deploy using ClickOnce. However, I will need the application to retrieve the query string parameters passed to it.

I found this MSDN article and followed its directions (select the check box labeled **Allow URL parameters to be passed to application)**, but it doesn't appear to work:

[How to: Retrieve Query String Information in a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms172242(en-us,vs.80).aspx)

ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri is null when the application loads.

eg:

http://example.com/Sample/Sample.application?a=1&b=2

Note: I'm not asking about passing the query string parameters to the setup.exe installation file for the application to work the first time when it is installed. Just the passing of query string to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! I needed to enable the same option from the Visual Studio IDE in addition to doing so from MageUI. I don't know how i missed it.

Comment: Can you answer following bit similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096708/download-customized-setup-from-url-with-the-query-string-parameters)